# Cycles and homology classes on quotient manifold

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, group-cohomology

I know that there are several questions here with answers about (co-)homology of quotient manifolds, and that they can in principle be computed with group cohomology.

My question is a bit more naive, I guess. Suppose that $\tilde{M} = M/G$, where the finite group $G$ acts freely on $M$. Because it is a free action, naively, a cycle $C$ in $M$ will always define a cycle $\tilde{C}$ in $\tilde{M}$ in the obvious way, i.e. $[p] \in \tilde{C} \subset M/G$ iff $p \in C \subset M$, where $[p]$ denotes the equivalence class of $p \in M$ in the quotient $M/G$. (Please correct me if that is wrong!).

My question is, if (and how) it is possible that cycles $C_{1/2}$ which represent the *same* integer homology class in $H_*(M, \mathbb{Z})$ can descend to curves $\tilde{C}_{1/2}$ in $\tilde{M}$ representing *different* classes in $H_*(\tilde{M}, \mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: Sorry if this question is stupid/useless/unnecessary from the point of view of certain people. If so, please briefly comment on as to why it is the case! From a simple down-vote I can't really learn anything...

Comment: Think about $3D$ lens spaces. In that case, $M=S^3$ has no first homology, but the quotient has $H_1=\mathbb Z_p$. So all homology classes lift to the same homology class in $S^3$, namely the trivial one.

Comment: Also, I just noticed that you talked about homology but used the notation for cohomology.

Comment: Thanks Jim, this example is helpful! The statement that $H_1(S^3)=0$ means that any 1-cycle in $S^3$ is the boundary of some 2-chain, right? So can I intuitively think about $H_1($quotient$) = \mathbb{Z}_p$ meaning that these 2-chains somehow descend in such a way to the quotient that they always have "$p$ curves" as their boundary?

Comment: Speaking about your question, it is **not** possible that homologous curves project to non-homologous ones. It is, however, possible that there are cycles downstairs that do not lift to cycles.

Comment: Concerning the lens space example, it depends on how you want to lift 1-cycles in the lens space to $S^3$. Either you take the preimage. Then upon descending again, you obtain p times the cycle you started with (or rather something homologous). Or you try to lift the cycle "bijectively". This is not possible for the generator of homology. You will end up with a non-closed curve in $S^3$.

Comment: Take a closed curve $C$ in a lens space $L(p,q)$ representing a generator of $H_1$. Itslift in $S^3$ is an arc with different endpoints.  The equality $pC=0$ in homology  signifies that if you take disjoint closed curves $C_1,\dotsc, C_p$, each representing the  same generator of $H_1$ then there exists an orinted surface $S\subset L(p,q)$ with boundary the union of the curves  $C_1,\dotsc, C_p$.